# Is there way to make WSO2 User Login Call using jQuery

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have got some documentation to get oAuth token from WSO2 API Manager.

http://www.yenlo.com/en/example-retrieving-oauth-token-based-username-password-wso2-api-manager-1-5-0/

But I need to know is there any way to make WSO2 User Login Call using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager exposes Login, Logout and much more operation through REST APIs, So, you could do the login with jQuery. For more details about the parameters and URLs have a look on [Published APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Published+APIs)